How the displacement of the MRD piston is calculated in this Above knee prosthetic?

given that BD is perpendicular on AB,
E is in the middle of BF,
lengths of AB, BD, BF, BE are known,
theta1 and theta2 are the angles of hip and knee respectfully, the ankle is considered fixed.
only DE is missing (the displacement of the MRD piston), and I need to link it to theta1 and theta2 so I can build the dynamic equations for the system.

Let us annotate the vertical line segment going down from joint B towards $\theta \ $, BV. V being the bottom end.
Angle BDE is the sum of the two angles, $ \angle BDE=\angle(EBV +VBD)$
Let us call the complementary angle to $\theta_1$ on the A joint angle K.
Angle K and angle VBD are equal because one side on both is vertical and the other sides are parallel.
$$\angle K=90-\theta_1= \angle VBD$$
$$DE=\frac{l_2}{2} sin\angle DBE= \frac{l_2}{2} sin\angle[((90-\theta_1)+\theta_2)]$$
We have all the parameters to solve for DE.
